# Why Illegal Argument Exception?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Dont Know why getting Illgal Argument Exception is crashing the android code.
Any help will be appreciated....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test_id); tv.append("\n");
    Uri u=Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    try{
        Toast.makeText(this, getContentResolver().delete(u, "_id like ?", new String[]{"2"})+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we have a stack trace? It would help immensely.

Answer (score 1):

The delete uri is "content://sms/" + id;

```
Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null,null);
try {
      while (c.moveToNext()) {
         int id = c.getInt(0);
         getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
      }

    }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e(this.toString(),"Error deleting sms",e);
    }finally {
      c.close();
    }
```

Comment: + is perfectly fine. Its not the error. i am just converting the returned result into string just by adding a blank.

Comment: A more standard way would be to call toString(), which is probably more efficient and definitely more readable.

Comment: Also, buptcoder is not actually complaining about the +, he is answering your question... you need to append an id to your uri.

Answer (score 0):

I think LIKE can only be used with String

```
Toast.makeText(this, getContentResolver().delete(u, "_id = ?", 
                    new String[]{"2"})+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You are right, I am not careful when reading. I thought you add "" to new String[]. Post your log cat